# Why is excel calculating percentages in thousands?

Tags: worksheet-function

I'm creating a report for my work wherein it takes all the daily stats and outputs a monthly report for all the team members regarding sign on time, calls taken, etc.

When I'm working out the percentages of available, wrap-up and unavailalbe, the individual days are fine, as they are done by manual input (copy/paste as values from another sheet).

I have created a "dashboard" style sheet at the front of the workbook which gives the monthly totals. I've used a 3D formula =AVERAGE('1:31'!P3) to take the percentages for all the individual days, but the result comes out in it's thousands.

Eg: One employee has available for the three days as 40%, 34% and 41%. In the "dashboard" sheet, it works out the average as 3846% instead of 38%. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see without looking at the specific spreadsheet is that there may be an issue with one of the data points you are including in the average being formatted as a number, instead of as a percentage, which would create this large value as a percentage in your average formula.

If you just take the average with a calculator normally you would get 38.33% and it seems like your thousands number is really close to that, but the decimal is in the wrong spot. If you do have the values formatted as a number and not a percentage, you can just add a /100 at the end of your average formula to get you back to your expected value instead of having to change all of the numbers individually to a percent, which can sometimes be a pain.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your suggestion, changing the format of the cell to a number, which worked. But it also worked *without* having to divide by 100. I set it as no decimal places and result came back as 38. When I changed the format back to percentage, it again went to 3846%.

This is quite frustrating lol

Comment: @IanScott, percentage takes a decimal fraction and multiplies it by 100 to display it as units of percent.  If your calculation is producing a result of 38, you're already multiplying it by 100 within that calculation or starting with units that are already percentages.  If you display that as percentage, it gets multiplied by 100 again.  You need to either calculate a fraction and then display that as percentage, or use your calculated number as-is and concatenate a percent sign onto it.

Comment: This makes sense. I've gone back and checked the sheet where I'm pulling the date from and the figures are in whole numbers (e.g. 38.1384267558). This is why it's showing percentages in the thousands. I'll just need to divide it by 100 then to get the correct figure. thank you for your help, it's very much appreciated!!